# method does not override or implement a method from a supertype @Override

Tags: react-native, bugsnag

I am using bugsnag-react-native version 2.2.3, I am getting below error while building in android
"method does not override or implement a method from a supertype @override"
and in ios, it's working fine.
and when i comment @override in node_modules/bugsnag-react-native/android/src/main/java/com/bugsnag/BugsnagReactNative.java file then it' successfully build.

I replaced this

```
@override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

to

```
//@override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

and it's working

when i use latest version so i am getting so many errors.
So please suggest, Dont want to change in node module.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in a later version. Could you try updating to the newest bugsnag-react-native version (2.7.0)?

Comment: Yes, It's solved but getting an error while using v-2.7.0, now it's resolved . Thanks